# Can I use a HC-05 and a GPS without a breadboard on a Arduino Uno?

Tags: gps, hc-05

I was wondering if I can use a GPS (in my case a U-BLOX) and a hc-05 at the same time connected to a arduino uno without a breadboard? I have tried my GPS on the arduino uno alone and it works very good. Now my question is, can I add a hc-05 on the board directly and put the VCC on the empty 5v?

I put together a schematic of what I had in mind below:

[image]

Would this schematic work or would I need a breadboard?

Comment: Are you expecting to use them both at once? Note of caution: you cannot reliably use two SoftwareSerial objects at once.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not. The breadboard is just something to help you prototype yuproect, in the end, your project should always be on a perfboard or a custom PCB.

Note that some male-female header might get handy.

I'm not sure that the HC05 can handle 5V though. You migh want to check.